# Configuring Nix Cardano Node for pre-production / preview

Tags: cardano-node, testnet, nix

The [build instructions using nix](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/getting-started/building-the-node-using-nix.md) for the cardano node are well documented, however they currently lack an option to build pre-production and preview testnet.

Does anyone know which config I could adjust to make them build these networks ?

I do know I could change configs under '/nix/store/...', but I don't think this is the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to [Cardano Testnet - Getting Started](https://docs.cardano.org/cardano-testnet/getting-started). It will explain **how to set up your node** for **Preview** and **Pre-Production** Testnet, complete with the configuration files.

There are also **different value for each networks**  `--testnet-magic INTEGER`:

- *Vasil devnet* : `9`
- *Preview* : `2`
- *Pre-production* : `1`

**This is the general steps from the docs:**

1. Build the latest cardano-node tag (currently 1.35.3)
2. Download the configuration file specifically made for each **Preview** or **Pre-Production** testnet
3. Run your node